# Two dimension int array custom dependencyProperty binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

Binding Source

```
    private int[,] _map = new int[22, 12] 
    {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    };
    public int[,] Map
    {
        get => _map;
        set => SetProperty(ref _map, value);
    }
```

DependencyProperty

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MapArrayProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register
        (
            "MapArray",
            typeof(int[,]),
            typeof(MapControl),
            new PropertyMetadata
            (
                null,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(MapArrayChanged)
            )
        );

    private static void MapArrayChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MapControl map = (MapControl)d;
        map.MapChanged();
    }

    public int[,] MapArray
    {
        get
        {
            return (int[,])GetValue(MapArrayProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MapArrayProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private void MapChanged()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<MapArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<MapArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Grid grid = new Grid();
                grid.Background = ColorSeletor(MapArray[i, j]);
                Grid.SetRow(grid, i);
                Grid.SetColumn(grid, j);
                GridMap.Children.Add(grid);
            }
        }
    }
```

start button binding source

```
    public ICommand StartCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    private void RandomBlockSelector()
    {
        IDefaultBlock defaultBlock = null;
        Random r = new Random();
        int selectedblock = r.Next(2, 9);
        switch (selectedblock)
        {
            case 2:
                defaultBlock = new IBlock();
                break;
            case 3:
                defaultBlock = new JBlock();
                break;
            case 4:
                defaultBlock = new LBlock();
                break;
            case 5:
                defaultBlock = new OBlock();
                break;
            case 6:
                defaultBlock = new SBlock();
                break;
            case 7:
                defaultBlock = new TBlock();
                break;
            case 8:
                defaultBlock = new ZBlock();
                break;
        }
        InsertBlock(defaultBlock.BlockArray);
    }

    private void InsertBlock(int[,] blockShape)
    {
        for(int i = 4; i<8; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j<5; j++)
            {
                Map[i, j] = blockShape[i - 4, j - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        RandomBlockSelector();
    }
```

If i start app, binding is working

[image: first start screen]

but if i click button, binding is not working
i think that when i click button to revise array
the array must be revise and a property change event
must occur to change view

If there is another way to bind a 2D array please let me know
or
could you find error in my code
[image: I want the picture after it is clicked]
[image: button click]

This is what should appear in the view after the button is clicked if it works

Comment: What you actually need is not an ObservableCollection (since your collection has a fixed number of elements). Instead, the element type should not be `int`, but a class with a `bool` property that indicates whether a cell is occupied or not. This class should implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and fire its PropertyChanged event in the setter of the bool property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the Disclaimer:

WPF, Windows forms and other Desktop application formats are not the right tool for game development. The right tool is anything with a [game loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure). XNA is slightly dated, but there is a whole list of possible [current frontends](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/gaming).

The issue is that your collection does not have Change notification in case a collection value changes. What you would need is a ObservableCollection or other "made for WPF" Collection. A `ObservableCollection<int>[]` - a array of ObservableCollection instances - is propably the droid you are looking for. But a `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>>` might be a better choice (you may want to use aliases to keep those types readable).

Comment: Thanks I didn't know the difference in binding of arrays and collections

Comment: @Teo it is not a Array vs Collection thing. It is a ObservableCollection vs all other Collections (arrays included) thing. Normally you would need 3 kinds of Change Notification with Collections in MVVM. But as you use primitive, inmutable types you can cut out the "per property" one. You may want to put some ChangeNotification into the Property Map. OC is terrible at bulk operations while exposed, so for bulk operations (like cleaning the field) you want to create a new instance, initialize it and only then expose it.